# Maximum ratio of the area of two regions?

Tags: geometry, area

**A regular hexagon is split into two regions by a straight line so that the ratio of the perimeters of these regions is 2:1. Find the maximum ratio of the areas of the two regions.**

This problem is inspired by one I saw on Brilliant.org today (credit goes to Digvijay Singh). It went as follows,

> An equilateral triangle is split into two regions with equal perimeters. Find the maximum ratio of the areas of the two regions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Side length is of no relevance here, hence we can assume it is unit without loss of generality.

The region to max/minimise is a quadrilateral, composed of a red triangle with base $x$ and altitude ${\sqrt3\over2}$, and a blue triangle with base $1-x$ and altitude ${\sqrt3\over2}(1+x)$ (see picture). The area of the region is therefore
$$
A={\sqrt3\over4}(1+x-x^2),
$$
which attains its maximum for $x=1/2$ and its minimum for $x=0$ or $x=1$.

From the above it is easy to answer the given question: details are left to the reader.